# Jersey - consume XML and HTML on POST

Tags: html, xml, rest, jersey, jax-rs

I would like to provide a flexible authentication method for my RESTful webservice - either via a HTML form or XML.  I realize that I can make an AJAX call from the HTML form, but I thought a simpler mechanism would be useful (especially during development).

If I annotate my SessionResource.createSession() method with @Consumes("application/xml","application/x-www-form-urlencoded"), it will accept both types of content.  The hard part is to differentiate the XML stream from the HTML.

Any guidance or thoughts would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why not do the following:

```
@...
class SessionResource{

 @POST
 @Consumes("application/xml")
 public void createSessionFromHTML(String message){
   ...
 }

 @POST
 @Consumes("application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
 public void createSessionFromXML(String message){
   ...
 }
}
```

In case this does not solve your problem please have a look at [@QueryParam](http://jsr311.java.net/nonav/releases/1.0/javax/ws/rs/QueryParam.html), [@HeaderParam](http://jsr311.java.net/nonav/releases/1.0/javax/ws/rs/HeaderParam.html) and [@FormParam](http://jsr311.java.net/nonav/releases/1.0/javax/ws/rs/FormParam.html).

This [overview](http://wikis.sun.com/display/Jersey/Overview+of+JAX-RS+1.0+Features) may also be of some use to you.

Comment: You are welcome. I think I will edit out the part about Scala since I ended up translating to java. :)